# Store large amout of data and update it on changes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native

I am currently building an app with Node.js, React Native and MongoDB, with a lot of data. The data is an array with objects containing image, description, username, and so on. For now, the user can click on the home page and get ALL data directly, but that takes a looot of time. Is there another way to do this? I was thinking about to cache all of the data (when the user visits the home page for the first time) and save it locally. And then maybe use triggers on database-changes?

Comment: not really enough details here, you can probably use pagination or lazy loading

Comment: Thank you! I compare my problem to the Instagram feed. There are a lot of data presented without it being slow.